# How can I format a string as a number (123) 456-7890

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, number-formatting, phone-number

I have a Caller.class which has a number stored as "1234567890," and I want the label lblCallbackNumber to be formatted as "(123) 456-789". This seems to be more complicated than I had though, and most web searches are showing people how to re-format a phone number as a regular number (the opposite of what I want)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
package SupportTool;

import javafx.scene.control.*;

import java.io.*;

public class mainCallController extends Main {

    public Label lblAccount;
    public Label lblCallbackNumber;
    public Label lblCallerName;
    public Label lblStoreNumber;

    public void initialize(){

        // LOAD CALLER INFORMATION
        Caller caller = new Caller();
        try{
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("caller.bin");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            caller = (Caller) ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
            fis.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // SET LABELS TO CALLER DETAILS
        lblAccount.setText(caller.getAccount());
        String numberAsString = caller.getCallbackNumber();
        lblCallbackNumber.setText(phoneFormat(numberAsString));
        lblCallerName.setText(caller.getCallerName());
        lblStoreNumber.setText(caller.getStoreNumber());

    }

    private String phoneFormat (String number){
        if(number.length() == 10) {

            // TODO RETURN numberAsString FORMATTED AS "(123) 456-7890"

        } else {
            return number;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Is it always 3 digits that go inside the `()`-brackets and is the number of digits between the brackets and the `-`  always 3? Can there be more `-` and where should they be inserted?

Comment: What have you tried to solve this? It should be fairly simple to take the first three numbers, put them in brackets, and place a dash between the remaining numbers...

Comment: @fabian The data coming in is always 10 digits as such: 1234567890. The data that I am trying to get is specifically as follows: (3-digits)[single space]3-digits[hyphen]4-digits. I am wanting it to ALWAYS be formatted this way, as my employees will copy that number in its specific number formatting.

Comment: Try extracting the groups as a substring (indices 0-2, indices 3-5, and 6-9), while inserting the desired characters between them.

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = "1234567890";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("(").append(s.substring(0,3)).append(") ").append(s.substring(3,6))
        .append("-").append(s.substring(6,9));
sb.toString();
```

Comment: Almost. The last substing should be `substring(6, 10)` or `substring(6)`, since there are 10 digits.

Comment: @fabian implemented based on his provided logic `1234567890` -> `(123) 456-789`

Comment: Most likely a typo, in since it also states `// TODO RETURN numberAsString FORMATTED AS "(123) 456-7890"`

Comment: @fabian you are correct, my goal is to give a workable and understandable solution, the fine tuning he can do for himself...

Answer (score 1):

You can use regexp for your task.
Something like this

```
number = number.replaceFirst("(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{4})", "($1) $2-$3");
```

This code will split your phone number onto 3 blocks (3 digits, 3 digits, 4 digits) and place them in order of the  pattern `"($1) $2-$3"`

The other way is to use StringBuilder to insert brackets and space

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(number)
                            .insert(0,"(")
                            .insert(4,") ")
                            .insert(8,"-");
```

But in my opinin regexp is more usefull and clear.

Comment: StringBuilder looks fairly easy to me, very understandable. I will also learn the regexp since it is what you recommended above stringbuilder. Thanks for you answer!

Comment: @Cormeistro you are welcome! Regexps sometimes are very usefull.But of course for your case stringBuilder is OK

Answer (score -1):

I just answered my own question with the discovery of .substring. It appears this is a very basic answer. Thanks for the help, as I just started learning java only 2 weeks ago.